# How can I efficiently compare contiguous and sequential rows using C# in Excel?

Tags: c#, range, vsto, excel-interop

I am developing a VSTO add-in for Excel in C# that needs to compare potentially large datasets (100 columns x ~10000 or more rows).  It is being done in Excel so an end user can view some pictorial representation of the provided data on a row-by-row basis.  This application must be done in Excel despite the potential pitfalls of using these large datasets.

Regardless, my question pertains to an efficient way to compare contiguous and sequential rows.  My goal is to compare one row to the row directly after it; if there is a change of any of the elements between row1 and row2, this counts as an "event" and row2 output into a separate sheet.  I'm sure you can see that for row-wise comparison of rows when the count is around 10000, this takes a long time (in practice, this is about 150ms-200ms per row for the current code).

Currently, I have used the `SequenceEqual()` method to compare two lists of strings as follows:

```
    private void FilterRawDataForEventReader(Excel.Application xlApp)
    {   
        List<string> row1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> row2 = new List<string>();

        xlWsRaw = xlApp.Worksheets["Full Raw Data"];
        xlWsEventRaw = xlApp.Worksheets["Event Data"];
        Excel.Range xlRawRange = xlWsRaw.Range["A3"].Resize[xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Rows.Count-2, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count];
        var array = xlRawRange.Value;

        Excel.Range xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWsEventRaw.Cells[xlWsEventRaw.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1];
        int lastRow = xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
        int newRow = lastRow + 2;

        for (int i = 1; i < xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            row1.Clear();
            row2.Clear();

            for (int j = 1; j <= xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count-1; j++)
            {                   
                row1.Add(array[i, j].ToString());
                row2.Add(array[i + 1, j].ToString());
            }
            if (!row1.SequenceEqual(row2))
            {
                row2.Add(array[i + 1, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count].ToString()); // Add timestamp to row2.
                for (int j = 0; j < row2.Count; j++)
                {
                    xlWsEventRaw.Cells[newRow, j + 1] = row2[j];
                }
                newRow++;
            }
        }           
    }
```

During testing, I placed timers are various parts of this method to see how long certain operations take.  For 100 columns, the first loop which builds the string arrays for row1 and row2 takes around 100ms per iteration and the whole operation takes between 150ms-200ms when an "event" has been found.

My intuition is that building the two `List<string>` is the problem but I do not know how else to approach this kind of problem in my experience.  I should emphasize, the actual values of the data in the two `List<string>` don't matter; what matters is if the data are different at all.  In that way, I feel that I am approaching this problem incorrectly but don't know how to "re-approach" so to say.

I am wondering if, instead of building arrays of strings through iteration and comparing them with the `SequenceEqual()` method, anyone can suggest a faster way to compare contiguous and sequential rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this solution may be useful for someone else trying to use Excel in C# and do some comparisons:

This problem was largely an optimization exercise.  By eliminating the multiple loops and using Excel instead to generate the comparison lists:

```
    for (int i = 3; i < xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
    {

        rng1 = (Excel.Range)xlWsRaw.Range[xlWsRaw.Cells[i, 1], xlWsRaw.Cells[i, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1]];
        rng2 = (Excel.Range)xlWsRaw.Range[xlWsRaw.Cells[i+1, 1], xlWsRaw.Cells[i+1, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1]];
        rng3 = (Excel.Range)xlWsEventRaw.Range[xlWsEventRaw.Cells[newRow, 1], xlWsEventRaw.Cells[newRow, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1]];

        object[,] cellValues1 = (object[,])rng1.Value2;
        object[,] cellValues2 = (object[,])rng2.Value2;
        List<string> test1 = cellValues1.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));
        List<string> test2 = cellValues2.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));

        if (!test1.SequenceEqual(test2))
        {
            rng2.Copy(rng3);
            xlWsEventRaw.Cells[newRow, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count].Value = xlWsRaw.Cells[i + 1, xlWsRaw.UsedRange.Columns.Count].Value; // Outputs the timestamp of the event to the events worksheet.
            newRow++;
        }
    }
```

I believe this can be optimized further but in my case, the ranges contain multiple types including strings so I convert everything to `List<string>` for the purpose of comparison.  The `SequenceEqual()` method, however it works behind the scenes, is nearly instantaneous and reduces the time to compare 120 columns to around 3ms.